# how to read sav file into r in a way that can be knitted in the R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to knit my R markdown into a pdf file.

This is how I read sav file into r

```
library(haven)
bes=read_sav(file.choose("Users/kn/Desktop/data.sav"))
```

But when I try to knit it, R markdown gives me an error

> file choice cancelled Calls: ...eval>eval>read_sav->  ->file choose Execution halted

Can someone help me out here, please?
Thanks :)

Comment: `file.choose` is an interactive window that you cannot use in a non-interactive environment like the one RMarkdown uses. Try just `read_sav("/Users/kn/Desktop/data.sav")` if that's the full path to the file.

Comment: Hi, this one doesn't work for me, it gives me an error saying that the dataset is not in the current working dictionary

Comment: Well you need to supply the full path to the file. Do you know the file's location? You can run `file.choose()` outside of markdown to get the path, then paste that path into the document.

Comment: Hi, it works. Thank you, really save my life!